# Is it possible to position a map view such that the user's current position is not in the center of the view?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm drawing a map within a view covering the entire device screen space.

On top of this view is another view occupying the bottom half of the screen. The top view is semi transparent and so the user can see the covered map beneath it.

Within the map I am displaying the user's current location.

The map view is automatically positioning the map such that the user's location is centered within the view - which is therefore the center of the device screen, however the center is also covered by the top view.

However I would like the user's location to be centered within the part of the map view that is not covered by the top view.

Comment: I'm sure there is probably a MKMapViewKit solution... but if you can't find one you could always just put the map view inside of a UIView called viewHolder then just translate viewHolder up whatever half-the-height of the other view is. Make sure viewHolder does NOT have clipping enabled. (Make your mkMapView frame larger as well to account for the translation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is to apply an offset to a coordinate to shift the map a little bit, taking advantage of the span of the region of the `MKMapView`.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCenter = userCoordinate;
newCenter.latitude -= _mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta * 0.50;
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:newCenter animated:YES];
```

Value of `0.50` is there just to give you an example. By changing it you can adjust the offset.

You can also take the current center position, convert it to a `CGPoint`, then add desired offset in pixels to a `CGPoint` and convert it back to `CLLocationCoordinate2D`:

```
UIOffset offset = UIOffsetMake(30.0f, 40.0f);
         offset.horizontal
         offset.vertical

CGPoint point = [_mapView convertCoordinate:userCoordinate
                              toPointToView:_mapView];
point.x += offset.horizontal;
point.y += offset.vertical;

CLLocationCoordinate2D newCenter = [_mapView convertPoint:point            
                                     toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];
[_mapView setCenterCoordinate:newCenter animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I could get the desired effect. But I can't seem to get it to work in combination with setting the zoom level. Is it possible to combine this with setRegion:? Calling your code snippet after a previous call to setRegion causes the "zoom-in" that i had set to be lost and instead of displaying a map of a few streets displays a map of the entire country. However if I move the call to setRegion to be after your code snippet then that makes it be centered in the view once more.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative answer. Please have a look.